# Как правильно использовать лямбда выражения в Java?

Tags: java

Всем доброго вечера! Есть некий код, использующий лямбда выражения.

```
public class Calculator {

    interface IntegerMath {

        int operation(int a, int b);
    }

    int operateBinary(int a, int b, IntegerMath op) {
        return op.operation(a, b);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Calculator myApp = new Calculator();
        IntegerMath addition = (a, b) -> a + b;
        IntegerMath subtraction = (a, b) -> a - b;
        System.out.println("40 + 2 = "
                + myApp.operateBinary(40, 2, addition));
        System.out.println("20 - 10 = "
                + myApp.operateBinary(20, 10, subtraction));
    }
}
```

Подобно этому надо реализовать нахождение `max`, `min`, `sum`, `count`. Знаю, что для этого можно использовать `SummaryStatistics`, но мне надо именно через эти выражения. Вот что есть у меня:

```
public class Solution2 {

    interface RandomDouble {
        double operation(double[] numbers);
    }

    public double operateBinary(double[] numbers, RandomDouble op) {
        return op.operation(numbers);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution2 myApp = new Solution2();
//        RandomDouble sum
//        RandomDouble max
//        RandomDouble min
        System.out.println("Sum: " + myApp.operateBinary(numbers, sum));
        System.out.println("Min: " + myApp.operateBinary(numbers, min));
        System.out.println("Max: " + myApp.operateBinary(numbers, max));
    }
}
```

Не знаю как прописать именно само выражение. Как это реализовать и возможно ли это? Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна реализация аггрегирующих операций.

Попробуем выразить операции итеративно:

Сумма (n + 1)-го элемента есть сумма n элементов плюс (n + 1)-ый элемент.
Максимум из (n + 1) элемента есть максимум из максимума n элементов и одного последнего элемента. Ну и количество (n + 1) элементов есть количество n элементов плюс 1.

Теперь реализуем это в коде:

```
int Aggregate(int startValue, int[] sequence, IntegerMath aggregator)
{
    int aggregatedValue = startValue;
    for (int currentValue : sequence)
        aggregatedValue = aggregator.operation(aggregatedValue, currentValue);
    return aggregatedValue;
}
```

В этим терминах легко реализовать, например, сумму:

```
int Sum(int[] addends)
{
    return Aggregate(0, addends, addition);
}
```

Немного сложнее максимум:

```
OptionalInt Max(int[] seq)
{
    if (addends.length == 0) return OptionalInt.empty();
    int result = Aggregate(Integer.MIN_VALUE, seq, (a, b) -> Integer::max(a, b));
    return OptionalInt.of(result);
}
```

Остальное вы легко додумаете сами.

Заметьте, что во многом то же самое делает Streams API из Java 8.